# convert string array to int

Tags: java

I am trying to convert a array with text and numbers to an int.

the array `separated`:

- separated[0] some text
- separated[1] 1
- separated[2] some more text

What I want is that the `[1]` ends up being a int.

I tried:

```
int logSetting = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(separated));
```

and

```
int logSetting = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(separated[1]));
```

Both made the app crash

> ```
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938): Process: my.project, PID: 27938
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int:
> ```
>
> "[Ljava.lang.String;@42b273f0"
>
> ```
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at my.project.MainActivity.fileReader(MainActivity.java:928)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at my.project.MainActivity.logCat(MainActivity.java:944)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at my.project.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:854)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
>
> 09-16 09:57:30.865: E/AndroidRuntime(27938):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Comment: put your logcat error

Comment: What kind of "crash" happened in second case? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: separated[1] 1. what does 1 without bracket mean here?

Comment: What exception you get?

Comment: did you try `Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);`? if you do `Integer.parseInt(separated[0]);` it should throw error, because text can't convert to int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
String[] separated=new String[]{"some text ","1","some more text"};
int logSetting = 0;
  for(String i:separated){
     try {
        logSetting = Integer.parseInt(i);
      }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException \""+i+"\" is not a number");
      }
     }
  System.out.println(logSetting);
```

Out put:

```
 NumberFormatException "some text " is not a number
 NumberFormatException "some more text" is not a number
 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, `int logSetting = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(separated[1]));` should just be `int logSetting = Integer.parseInt(separated[1]);`. If this doesn't work its probably something else crashing your code. What error do you get?

Comment: are you sure about your answer? the op got numberformatexcepion

Comment: If all he has in the index [1] is "1" this should not throw the exception. If it does I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your exception which is `NumberFormatException`, when you try to  convert a String to a numeric value, like an int, float, double, long, etc which does not have right format

For example:

```
public class ConvertStringToNumber
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      String s = "FOOBAR";
      int i = Integer.parseInt(s); <--this line of code will never be reached
      System.out.println("int value = " + i);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
      nfe.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

1. [Source for the Code](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-faq-what-is-numberformatexception)
2. [Read more and Another Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)